# supabase auth listeners causing infinite rerendering

Tags: reactjs, next.js, supabase, supabase-js

My app is wrapped in a provider that should pass the session state to the rest of the app. But the supabase auth listener code seems to infinitely rerender my component and I cannot figure out how to fix it. The provider code:

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { createClient } from "@supabase/supabase-js";
import { supabasekey } from "../../constants";

const supabaseUrl = "https://**************.supabase.co";
const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabasekey["1"]);

const MyContext = createContext();

const AppStateProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(/* initial state */);

  //Supabase auth functions causing infinite re-rendering of components
  useEffect(() => {
    supabase.auth.getSession().then(({ data: { session } }) => {
      setState(session?.user ?? null);
    });

    supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((_event, session) => {
      setState(session?.user ?? null);
    });
  }, []);

  console.log("provider running");

  // Create the context value
  const contextValue = {
    state,
    setState,
  };

  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={contextValue}>{children}</MyContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { MyContext, AppStateProvider };
```

my app code

```
    <>
      <AppStateProvider>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
      </AppStateProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a check for `if (event === 'SIGNED_IN')`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    supabase.auth.getSession().then(({ data: { session } }) => {
      setState(session?.user ?? null);
    });

    const {
      data: { subscription }
    } = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((event, session) => {
      if (event === 'SIGNED_IN') setState(session?.user ?? null);
    });

    return () => {
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    };

  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's resolved in https://github.com/supabase/gotrue-js/issues/762.
It's because you are trying to use getSession in asyn.